# cannot read property 'getDirection' of undefined

Tags: ckeditor

Using ckeditor 4.4.7, I keep getting the following errors...  Does any one have any ideas what I need to fix?

```
Cannot read property 'getDirection' of undefined 
Cannot read property 'allow' of undefined
```

I'm using CKEDITOR.inline(DIVid, config) to create the editor that modifies
a DIV with contenteditable='true' attribute

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
    <p>The "div" element that contains this text is now editable.
</div>
```

Or this:

```
<div id="editor1" contenteditable="true">
    <h1>Inline Editing in Action!</h1>
    <p>The "div" element that contains this text is now editable.
</div>
<script>
    // Turn off automatic editor creation first.
    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.inline( 'editor1' );
</script>
```

Hopefully either will help you. If they don't, then make sure the div is on the page before the event is called (document.ready()) and make sure that all of your scripts are being loaded before you make any calls to CKEDITOR.

Source: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_inline